# ¿Como obtener el primer registro de una tabla?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Espero me puedan apoyar comunidad, estoy realizando la siguente consulta:

```
SELECT
 CB.Codigo as 'Codigo/UPC',
 CB.SubCuenta,
 CB.Cuenta
FROM InvD
JOIN Inv as I on I.ID = InvD.ID
JOIN CB on InvD.SubCuenta = CB.SubCuenta and InvD.Articulo = CB.Cuenta
WHERE I.FechaEmision >= '2023-05-01' and I.MovID = 'CHOQR6' and I.Mov = 'Recibo Traspaso'
```

En esta consulta de arroja `44 registros` pero vienen duplicados, por que con el join hacia `CB` es donde me arroja:

```
select * from CB where Cuenta = '570338139CIW03' and CB.SubCuenta = 'C42T79'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los cuales son los mismo dos resultados que me da en mi consulta principal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi me va duplicando por cada registro cuando hay mas de uno en la tabla de CB, ¿Hay alguna manera de que me traiga el primer registro de cada uno ? Para no tener duplicados, se los agradecería mucho si pudieran ayudarme.

Yo trate de realizar una subconsulta en el join

```
select top 1 Codigo, Cuenta, SubCuenta from CB as Cod where CB.Codigo = Cod.Codigo and 
CB.Cuenta = Cod.Cuenta and Cod.SubCuenta = CB.SubCuenta
```

pero no tuve el resultado que quería.

Comment: Para que vas a la tabla ART?

Comment: Si la uso, en el ejemplo quite muchos campos para que no fuera tan grande la consulta y esa no me afecta en nada. Y es para obtener las descripciones de mis articulos.

Comment: ¿Cual es la tabla que  produce los "duplicados"? ¿podrías agregar el query completo?

Comment: Es la de CB, ahi esta en la pregunta con un ejemplo en especifico. Y la segunda imagen es el resultado de la primer consulta.

Comment: pero no son duplicados, se puede ver que el código es diferente. En este caso, cuál es el registro que sería el "primero"?, tienes alguna fecha o algo similar?

Comment: Bueno, disculpa tienes razón! no son duplicados si no que trae los dos registros que se unen con la cuenta y subcuenta, son con códigos distintos. Lo que busco es que solo me traiga el primero para el analisis que requiero no afecta cual traiga, ya con la cuenta y subcuenta es mas que suficiente.

Comment: ¿Y como se determina cual es el primer registro de los dos?

Comment: SI no afecta, entonces tu query esta mal ;)... si sobran columnas, tu query esta mal... si hay datos de mas, tu query esta mal.. primero, quedate con lo que realmente queres.. y vas a ver como tus problemas casi se solucionan solos...

Comment: Si los ocupo, ya lo quite en mi pregunta para que no haya confunsión pero sigo con el mismo problema, todo esta en CB.

Comment: antes dijiste que no importaba.. esa columna, importa o no??? si importa, con que criterio te quedas con una o con otra?? si no importa, para que la traes???

Comment: Hagamos como que no paso nada de esto, ya edité la pregunta y no la estoy trayendo ni mandando a llamar en ningún momento, me sigue saliendo el mismo problema, sigue tomando los dos registros de mi tabla CB, hay una manera para que puedo solo tomar el primero?¿

Comment: Tu primer query está rara, porque usas `FROM InvD` pero en el `SELECT` no mandas a llamar a nada de esa tabla, si la usas la deberías poner en el `JOIN` y no en el `FROM`. Otra cosa, en lugar de `JOIN` general, deberías usar uno en concreto, `INNER, LEFT, RIGHT` etc... Y por ultimo sin por lo menos un Snippet de tu ambiente creo que es complicado, usa algún [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) de SQL para poder hacer pruebas.

Answer (score 0):

Podes probar poniendo como primer parametro del select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
...
FROM ...
```

O usar Group by al final de la query

```
SELECT
...
FROM
...
GROUP BY [todas las columnas del select]
```